# Is it possible to consume Firehose as input to Apache Flink on AWS Kinesis Data Analytics?

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-analytics

Like AWS Kinesis Data Analytics SQL(legacy), Is it possible for the flink application on KDA to consume as firehose input stream ?

Comment: Questions that are phrased in a way that can be answered with "yes" or "no" are unlikely to get great answers.

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/firehose/#notice) for the Kinesis Data Firehose SQL Connector has this to say:

> The current implementation for the Kinesis Data Firehose SQL connector only supports Kinesis Data Firehose backed sinks and doesn’t provide an implementation for source queries. Queries similar to:
>
> `SELECT * FROM FirehoseTable;`
>
> should result in an error similar to
>
> `Connector firehose can only be used as a sink. It cannot be used as a source.`

This means that the connector that's included in Flink doesn't support using Firehose as a source.

In addition, Firehose is not really intended for streaming output. It's intended for loading the data from a stream input into other data sources such as S3, Elasticsearch or Redshift. So I guess that implies that a Firehose wouldn't be suitable as a Flink source.